# How can I stop MediaPlayer without error when I press Back or go to another activity

Tags: android, media-player

I created a Karaoke application. But I can't stop the MediaPlayer with out an error. When I press Back Button to go to home, I get "sorry ,Application has stopped working"  The same thing happens if I try to start another activity.

This my code.

```
public class Main extends Activity implements MediaPlayerControl, OnClickListener {
private MediaController mMediaController;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
public TextView subtitles;
Handler mHandler = new Handler();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    subtitles = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subs1);
    Button btnvol = (Button) findViewById(R.id.volc);
    btnvol.setOnClickListener(this);

    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaController = new MediaController(this);

    mMediaController.setMediaPlayer(Main.this);
    mMediaController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.audioView));

    try {
        mMediaPlayer
                .setDataSource(
                        this,
                        Uri.parse("android.resource://com.app.audioplayer/raw/buchatri"));
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mHandler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.handleMessage(msg);
              final long currentPos = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
              if (currentPos < 5130) {
                    subtitles.setText("Stupid");
                } else if (currentPos > 5130 && currentPos < 10572) {
                    subtitles.setText("Sorry");
                } else if (currentPos > 10572 && currentPos < 10597) {
                    subtitles.setText("555+");
                } else if (currentPos > 15312 && currentPos < 18478) {
                    subtitles.setText("OMG");
                } else if (currentPos > 18478 && currentPos < 24191) {
                    subtitles.setText("AFK");
                } else if (currentPos > 24191 && currentPos < 28137) {
                    subtitles.setText("Help me !");
                } else if (currentPos > 28137 && currentPos < 29500) {
                    subtitles.setText("Oh no !");
                }
              mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 1);
        }
    };
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);


    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mMediaController.show(0);
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mMediaPlayer.stop();
    mMediaPlayer.release();
}

public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
}

public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return true;
}

public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return true;
}

public int getBufferPercentage() {
    int percentage = (mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() * 100)
            / mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
    return percentage;
}

public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
}

public int getDuration() {
    return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
}

public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}

public void seekTo(int pos) {
    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(pos);

}

public void start() {
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    mMediaController.show(0);
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

I think I have an error with "if else". How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

after release you should set mediaplayer null

```
private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try first `mMediaPlayer.stop()` and then release it by `mMediaPlayer.release()`